# Xamarin UI Test App project template missing on MAC

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add Xamarin Ui Test project but there is no tests under the multiplatform. My visual studio version is 17.6.3 is there a way to add it via console?

I'm trying to add Xamarin Ui Test but there is no project template in Multiplatform test.